# Loading a Partial View by name stored in ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

How would I correctly load a partial with a value from the viewbag?

I currently have:

```
@Html.Partial(@ViewBag.PartialViewName)
```

but it's not working

also have tried it like:

```
@Html.Partial(ViewBag.PartialViewName)
```

how can I pass the value of the viewbag.partialviewname into the @html.Partial

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i ended up doing it was like so:

```
@{
    string pvn =   @ViewBag.PartialViewName;  
}
@Html.Partial( pvn )
```

Answer (score 2):

Viewbag is a dynamic property so you need to tell MVC what it is. Try putting a ToString() at the end but ensure that the value is never null. If it is, you'll need to wrap it in an If statement or use an expression.